# Add item to Select-Object or Format-Table

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have below powershell script which returns me the list of services running from a specific account on different servers:

```
$servers = @(
    "Server1",
    "Server2"       
)

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    Write-Host $server      
    Get-WMIObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $server | Where-Object{$_.StartName -eq 'serviceaccount'} | Sort-Object -Property StartName | Format-Table Name, StartName
}
```

And this returns me results like:

```
Server1
Name                                          StartName                                     
----                                          ---------
AdobeARMservice                               serviceaccount
PlugPlay                                      serviceaccount

Server2
Name                                          StartName                                     
----                                          ---------
UxSms                                         serviceaccount
```

Now I would like to add the name of the server in the list as well and get results displayed something like:

```
Name                StartName              Server
----                ---------              -------
AdobeARMservice     serviceaccount         Server1
PlugPlay            serviceaccount         Server1
UxSms               serviceaccount         Server2
```

Comment: Some suggestions:  
1. Filter the list of services in the Get-WMIObject statement, like this:  
    * "Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "startname='serviceaccount'" -ComputerName $server", then remove the Where-Object.  
2. Remove the Sort-Object.  If you're filtering for only services where the StartName is equal to something, then you're sorting a list where there's nothing to sort.  They're all the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```
... | Format-Table Name, StartName, @{n="Server";e={$server}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend what's being returned by using Select-Object as follows:

```
select-object Name, StartName, @{Name='Server';Expression={$server}}
```

You should remove Write-Host so as not to interfere with the results:

```
$servers = @(
    "Server1",
    "Server2"       
)

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    Get-WMIObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $server | `
        Where-Object{$_.StartName -eq 'serviceaccount'} | ` 
        select-object Name, StartName, @{Name='Server';Expression={$server}} | `
        Sort-Object -Property StartName | `
        Format-Table Name, StartName, Server
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The WMI class [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) already contains server's name, so just pick it from `PSComputerName` member like so,

```
foreach($server in $servers){
    gwmi Win32_Service -ComputerName $server | % {$_.StartName -eq '...'} |`
    sort -Property StartName | ft Name, StartName, PSComputerName
}
```